# How did Google Ads find out my campaign's conversion even if customer visited different HTML page before firing final tracking code?

Tags: google-tag-manager, ads, google-ads-api, gtag.js

I have set up a Google Ads campaign.

If users search "Cool Clothes" in Google, my campaign website will show in search results.

Now, the user will follow these steps:

1. Click the campaign website link in the Google search result
2. Go to https://cool-clothes.com/my-campaign
3. The user wants to signup an account, so users click the "Sign Up" button
4. I use Facebook for login, so users will redirect to https://facebook.com first, asking for some permissions.
5. After permission granted, Facebook will redirect back to my website called https://cool-clothes.com/new-user
6. https://cool-clothes.com/new-user is where I put the Google Ads tracking code

https://cool-clothes.com/new-user HTML looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Cool Clothes</title>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) -->
    <script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-XXX"
    ></script>

    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag("js", new Date());

      gtag("config", "AW-XXX");
    </script>

    <!-- Event snippet for conversion page -->
    <script>
      gtag("event", "conversion", {
        send_to: "AW-XXX/XXX",
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Thanks for Sign Up!
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here comes my question, the user goes through multiple different HTML pages, how did Google Ads know how to count the conversion?**

Are Google Ads using first-party **cookies** to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes.

GA uses a user identifier cookie that identifies the user. And more on top of that. And it's able to "backfill" user's actions preceding the conversion as such that led to conversion. And a lot more on top of that.

It's also not a secret, Google has documentation on it: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2407785?hl=en